# Grobs are not plotted at all or in wrong position

Tags: r, ggplot2, grob

I am having trouble understanding how grobs are being placed into the plotting area.
Here's an example of what I mean.
Let's assume I have the following plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)
p <- mpg %>%
  ggplot(aes(year)) +
  geom_bar() 
p
```

[image]

I understand that I can get a list of grobs from that and plot it like so.

```r
l <- ggplotGrob(p)
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(l)
```

From the structure of list `l` I also understand that the rectangles are drawn as `rectGrob`s. I found these in.

```r
grobs <- l$grobs[[6]]
rect_grobs <- grobs$children[[3]]
```

But if I want to plot at least one rectangle using the data straight from `rect_grobs`, nothing happens. This is independent of whether I create a new canvas with `grid::grid.newpage()` or not.

```r
# This draws nothing
grid::grid.draw(
  grid::rectGrob(
    x = rect_grobs$x[1],
    y = rect_grobs$y[1],
    height = rect_grobs$height[1],
    width = rect_grobs$width[1],
    just = rect_grobs$just[1],
  )
)
```

Yet if I plug in the values from `rect_grobs` by hand, then a rectangle is drawn in the wrong position. I suspect that this is related to viewports but I tried looking in `l`, `grobs` and `rect_grobs` but I found no clue what viewport so set. Wherever I look, there is only `vp = NULL`.

```r
# This draws in wrong position
grid::grid.draw(
  grid::rectGrob(
    x = 0.0455,
    y = 0.955,
    width = 0.431,
    height = 0.909,
    just = 'left'
  )
)
```

[image]

So, my questions are

1. Why does the code not draw a rectangle if I take the values straight from the `rect_grobs` list?
2. How do I get the rectangle into the correct position if I manually add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `rect_grobs` doesn't draw is indeed that it has no viewport. If a grob has no viewport set, it will inherit from its parent, but since you have plucked it out of a `gTable`, it has no parent. This is easy to rectify by giving it a default viewport:

```r
rect_grobs$vp <- grid::viewport()
grid::grid.draw(rect_grobs)
```

[image]

As long as we specify the correct `just`, we get the rectangle in the same place:

```r
red_rect <-   grid::rectGrob(
    x = 0.0455,
    y = 0.955,
    width = 0.431,
    height = 0.909,
    just = c("left", "top"),
    gp = grid::gpar(fill = "red")
  )

grid::grid.draw(red_rect)
```

[image]

However, this is not the position the rectangle would be in a ggplot. That's because in `ggplot` the panel has its own viewport. To draw the rectangle in this context, we need to navigate to the correct viewport before calling `grid.draw`

```
plot(p)

grid::seekViewport(grid::vpPath("layout", "panel.7-5-7-5"))

grid::grid.draw(red_rect)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent solution. Thank you. Do you happen to know a ressource e.g. a book where I can read up on how grid works? I feel like I was close to the solution but lacked a bit of background knowledge to make it work in the end.

Comment: Most of what I have learned has been from tinkering, and from Stack Overflow. [This book chapter](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/RProgDA/the-grid-package.html) is helpful, and also has a couple of useful links. The ultimate guide is probably [Paul Murrell's book](https://www.routledge.com/R-Graphics-Third-Edition/Murrell/p/book/9780367780692) but I have to admit I have not (yet) read it.